# Communication between 2 dockerized spring boot applications using custom docker network

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Hello service and World service. The Hello service has a rest point /hello/hw which internally calls rest end point in World service to return string "Hello World".
The application works fine as expected if the system is not dockerized.

However the issue is when I want to dockerize the system.
I use docker-compose to containerize both services. I have defined a custom network in the docker compose file (named as custom_net).

The rest end point /hello/hw is reachable but Hello service is not able to call the rest end point in the World service.

The application.properties in Hello service has the url of World service as http://localhost:8082/world

I get UnknownHostException when I set the url as http://custom_net:8082/world or to http://custom_net:8092/world

I get Connection refused exception when I don't change the url in application.properties.
The log message states 'failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8082;'
I am not sure what configurations are needed to bridge the 2 services

The command docker network list shows the name of custom network as 'tempfolder_custom_net'.
The command docker inspect shows that both hello and world service are registered to this network

```
version: '3'
services:
  hello_service:
    image: 'openjdk:8-jdk-alpine'
    restart: always
    container_name: hello_service
    volumes:
    - ./deploy:/root
networks:
- custom_net
depends_on:
- world_service
command: sh -c "java -jar -Dspring.config.location=file:///root/hello/application.yml  /root/hello/hello-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar "
ports:
- 8091:8081

world_service:
image: 'openjdk:8-jdk-alpine'
restart: always
container_name: world_service
volumes:
- ./deploy:/root
command: sh -c "java -jar -Dspring.config.location=file:///root/world/application.yml  /root/world/world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar "
ports:
- 8092:8082
networks:
- custom_net

networks:
  custom_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Application.yml of Hello service ...

```
 server:
      port: 8081
    services:
      world:
        url: http://localhost:8082/world
```

Comment: try to call `http://world_service:8092/world`

Comment: "http ://world_service:8092/world" gives connection refused exception.
"http ://world_service:8082/world" gives bad request 400 error

Comment: how did you call to word service from hello service ? how to configure URL call in the code ? btw check `http://172.17.0.1:8092/world`

Comment: In Hello service I am using WebClient. The webClient gets the base url from application.properties. I do not want to hard code the ip. Is it a standard practice in production environment to hardcode ip address?

Comment: can you share URL from application.properties file , and check `http://172.17.0.1:8092/world` ?

Comment: in my case the world service was on 172.25.0.3. With this added in application.yml, the Hello service tries to call World service but doesn't get connected. I get time out exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Thanh Nuguyen Van thanks for providing useful hints in troubleshooting.
The issue was with the host name world_service. Looks like underscore is not a valid URL. Below is my updated docker compose file. I didn't even have to use custom docker network. I updated the url in application.yml to http://worldservice:8082/world.
Also note that the port is 8082 not 8092. We have to mention the application's port and not the docker exposed port.

```
version: '3'
services:
  helloservice:
    image: 'openjdk:8-jdk-alpine'
    restart: always
    container_name: helloservice
    volumes:
    - ./deploy:/root
    #networks:
    #- custom_net
    depends_on:
    - worldservice
    command: sh -c "java -Xdebug -jar -Dspring.config.location=file:///root/hello/application.yml  /root/hello/hello-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar "
    ports:
    - 8091:8081
  worldservice:
    image: 'openjdk:8-jdk-alpine'
    restart: always
    container_name: worldservice
    volumes:
    - ./deploy:/root
    command: sh -c "java -Xdebug -jar -Dspring.config.location=file:///root/world/application.yml  /root/world/world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar "
    ports:
    - 8092:8082
    #networks:
    #- custom_net
#networks:
  #custom_net:
    #driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

You should build new image base on `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine` image, and add ENTRYPOINT

You should change this:

```
server:
      port: 8081
    services:
      world:
        url: http://localhost:8082/world
```

To :

```
server:
      port: 8081
    services:
      world:
        url: http://world_service:8092/world
```

Make sure, both containers are running.

Comment: This did not solve the issue. I get "Connection refused: worldservice/172.18.0.2:8092"

Comment: Can please elaborate on why new image base needs to be used. My existing image base is the same. Also what needs to mentioned in ENTRYPOINT. Is the command not sufficient? I am able to access Hello service and World service api independently

Comment: Nuguyen Van The url should be http://worldservice:8082/world. The port number should be of the application and not the docker exposed port and the host name should be worldservice (underscore removed)

Comment: does it work with new configuration ?

Comment: yes. Only difference is that custom docker network is not used.